# Intel XDK jquery mobile button doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, intel-xdk

I´m having some problem working an easy example in the Intel XDK coded in jquery mobile. The button doesn´t work and I did´t found why. 
I posted the full code but is a single button and a query selector to open an alert and write in the console.
Please any help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqm/jquery.mobile-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/humedad_main.less.css" class="main-less">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="xhr.js"></script>
    <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="jqm/jquery.mobile-min.js" data-ver="0"></script>
    <script>
              $(document).on("pagecreate","#mainpage",function(){
                  $('#boton2').bind('click', function(){
                      console.log('pagina cargada');
                      alert('me tiene hasta los huevos');
                });
              });  
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="upage" id="mainpage" data-role="page">
      <div class="upage-outer">
        <div data-role="header" class="container-group inner-element uib_w_1" data-uib="jquery_mobile/header" data-ver="0">
          <h1>HUMEDAD</h1>
          <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
          <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
          <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="upage-content content-area vertical-col left" id="page_59_24">
          <button id="boton2">grafica 2</button> 

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: im having same problem. I find however if I use a document ready and place the script into the body of my page it works! Strange

Comment: Hello. Finally I solved it. When you use $(document).ready you are calling query cdn. When using $(function(){}) Is the same as document ready but using Jquery mobile syntax